# Constructing dynamic table using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table

[image]

1. I have to design table like mentioned in image
2. Here, impact and urgency values are dynamic, for example if I gave urgency 3 and impact 3, then it should be 3 urgency rows and 3 impact columns
3. I tried, I able to construct table dynamically, but how to give headers exactly like given in image.

```
$("#table").append("<table id=''><tr><th>Priority Matrid</th><th>Impact</th></tr><tr></tr></table>");
for(var i=0;i<urgencyValues.length;i++) {
    $("#priorityMatrixTable").append("<th>"+impactValues[i]+"</th>");
    for(var i=0;j<impactValues.length;j++) {
    }
}
```

I don't know how to proceed further...

Comment: You need to show the code you tried and explain more specifically what problems you are having with that code. A demo would be very helpful since we have no data structure to work from

Answer (score 1):

First column head needs th attribute rowspan=2